# Why is GnuRadio companion not allowing me to add blocks?

Tags: gnuradio, gnuradio-companion

I have installed GNU Radio and GRC 3.7.2.2 on a 32bit XP machine following the instructions from Ettus. It starts without any messages, I can open an existing flowgraph, delete blocks, edit block properties, but I cannot add new blocks. Double click on the block has no effect. Nor does dragging it, right clicking it or any other gesture I could think of. Can anyone think of a problem that might be causing this?

Update: it turns out that Return works, not double-click

Comment: See here, that worked for me: https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/15702/find-blocks-function-on-gnuradio-does-not-work

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are having issues with the installed graphics libraries. Did you install the whole list of dependencies in those instructions?

You should e-mail the GNU Radio mailing list with what's going on: https://lists.gnu.org/mailman/listinfo/discuss-gnuradio